# Fiware Orion Context Broker 2.2.0 in Docker - stop to send notifications after a while

Tags: notifications, fiware-orion

We are experiencing problems with the notifications sent by Orion for new data after the last update to version 2.2.0.

Orion is run inside a Docker container.

Specifically, the problem is this:
when we start the docker container, every endpoint is contacted when a new data arrives. But then, after a while (less than 1 day), some endpoints (currently, the one hosted by Amazon Web Service) stopped to be contacted. The error obtained is: 'notification failure for sender-thread: Timeout was reached'

As additional information,
if we try to send data manually (through a CURL request performed in a bash instance inside the docker container) it works fine. While Orion cannot contact the endpoint falling in a "Timeout" exception.

Furthermore, if we restart the container (with consequent deletion of the contextBroker.pid from the dedicated folder in (/var/lib/docker/overlay2/)), it starts to push data again.

[Linked issue on github](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3530)

Comment: After monitoring the resource allocation of the Context Broker I can see this situation:

    when the context broker is run it needs less the 20% of CPU to perform all his features (i.e., send a notification to all the subscribed endpoints when a new data is received)
    during a day long the CPU allocation continues to grow and, when we notice a loss of information it arrives at 100% (after almost 24 hours)

So maybe there is a bug that cause this issue?